# Configure webpack for vue such that backend express server is in ECMA2016

Tags: express, vue.js, webpack

I wrote an app using the `webpack`-boilerplate for `vue`. The backend handling `GET` and `POST` requests is an `express`-server. IDE is visual studio code.

This is what I did:

```shell
$ vue init webpack app
$ cd app
$ npm install
$ npm install axios express body-parser node-sass sass-loader
$ npm install --save-dev concurrently nodemon
```

`app/express/app.js` looks like:

```js
//import express from express
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
// sets port 8080 to default or unless otherwise specified in the environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080)

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')    
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../dist/`))

// Test: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"path": "bla/blub.txt"}' http://localhost:8081/api/save
app.post('/api/save', function (req, res) {
    response = {
        msg: 'okay',
        data: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response))
})

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

I modified the boilerplate code generated by `vue init webpack` such that `app/components/HelloWorld.vue` is:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api"
export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
        }
    },
    async created() {
        this.msg = await Axios.post(`${baseUrl}/save`, {"path": "bla/blub.txt"})
            .then(response => new Promise(resolve => {
                let msg = response.data.msg
                resolve(msg)
            }))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                Promise.reject(error)
            })
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
```

To start development in one command (`npm start go`) and allow hot reloading, I changed `app/package.json` (don't know where I copied that from):

```js
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "apiserver": "PORT=8081 nodemon express/app.js",
    "go": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run dev\" \"npm run apiserver\"",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
```

To start the dev version of the app, I ran:

```
$ npm run dev   # webpack-dev-server starts on port 8080, express on 8081
```

To avoid CORS-problems, webpack can be configured to proxy express requests. Change `app/config/index.js`:

```js
proxyTable: {
'/api':{
    target: 'http://localhost:8081',
    changeOrigin: true,
 }
},
```

One can now run `npm run dev` from `app/` again, everything works fine.

Hence, over to production mode. I run

```
$ npm run build
$ node express/app.js
```

Everything runs fine.

(Over time, I added answers found by myself into this question... The original question was: "Configure webpack for vue frontend and express backend (scenario both production and development)")

My question is now:

How to change webpack babel setup such that the `node`-run file `app.js` uses ECMA2016 (such that `import express from express` can be used instead of `require ...`)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The long preamble to the question is due to the fact the my original question was quite different; over time, I added solutions I found...